# Using Windows 11 Home and Outlook Version 2308 and Office 365 how do I setup an address list to search in?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I am trying to set up an OOC message to reply to all messages except from a group.io message.
I succeeded in setting up the Alert but when I try to set up the exception address from group.io I am unable to choose the address because the address list has not been set. The message says that the address list has not been set up by the Microsoft Exchange Administrator.  Where do I find this setup?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot without private information so that we can understand better about the situation?

Comment: Hi Yuki Sun here is a link to the screenshot you requested https://1drv.ms/i/s!AlRtpcoYYMui83PAnLXfLQ0z9onQ?e=hdwlEM

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you are trying to create rule to reply all mails except from group.io, right?
If by "a group.io message", you mean the sender's email address containing "group.io", you can choose the exception rule below instead:
**except with specific words in the sender's address**

[image]

Comment: Hi Yuki Sun I will try that thank you.

Comment: Have a go at your convenience and don't forget to come back and accept the answer if it can work :-)